# Variable handling in Shellscript

Tags: shell

I have a file called `param.txt` which contains like below:

```
JOHN
Dheer
Rahul
```

I want to parametrize like different variable should contain different values:

```
v1=JOHN
v2 =Dheer
v3=Rahul
```

I am trying ike below:

```
export COUNT=1

for PN in $(cat /home/hadoop/rahul/param_test.txt)
do

    #echo "$PN"
    V$COUNT=$PN

    echo `${V$COUNT}`

    COUNT= 'expr $COUNT + 1'
done
```

It should name the variable as per count.
I am  getting error.Can anybody suggest anything.

Comment: I've changed the formatting in your code. In your `param.txt` sample, I deleted the blank lines. Please confirm that that's consistent with what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many syntax errors. Here is the corrected one:

```
count=1

while read -r line; do
   echo "v${count}=$line"
   count=`expr $count + 1`
done < /home/hadoop/rahul/param_test.txt
```